# Using RegisterHotKey to register hot key using Numpad

Tags: c#, user32, registerhotkey, global-hotkey, numpad

I have used `RegisterHotKey` for registering a global hotkey for my application.
I need to register Control + Shift + 0 (in numpad) for the application.
I have registered it using the below code snippet:

```
RegisterHotKey(_mainWindowHandle, 1, (uint)ModifierKeys.Control | (uint)ModifierKeys.Shift | 0X4000, (uint)Keys.NumPad0);
```

However it not responding as expected, other hotkeys are getting registered, only the above combination is not responding.

Comment: Sure, when you hold down the Shift key then the numpad keys generate a different code.  NumPad0 becomes Insert.  The state of the NumLock key matters too, so probably not a great choice for a hotkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shift + Numpad generated a different code, hence Ctrl+Shft+Numpad was not producing expected result. I found a workaround by changing the shortcut from Ctrl+Shift+Numpad to Ctrl+Numpad.